# How to split single text file into multiple with character as delimiter

Tags: java, parsing

I have a text document that has multiple separate entries all compiled into one .log file.

The format of the file looks something like this.

```
$#UserID#$
Date
User
UserInfo
SteamFriendID
=========================
<p>Message</p>
$#UserID#$
Date
User
UserInfo
SteamFriendID
========================
<p>Message</p>
$#UserID#$
Date
User
UserInfo
SteamFriendID
========================
<p>Message</p>
```

I'm trying to take everything in between the instances of "$#UserID$#", and print them into separate text files.

So far, with the looking that I've done, I tried implementing it using StringBuilder in something like this.

```
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(“Path to raw file.”);
        int idCount = 1;
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Path to parsed files" + idCount);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //String line, date, user, userInfo, steamID;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.substring(0,1).contains("$#")) {
                if (sb.length() != 0) {
                    File file = new File("Path to parsed logs" + idCount);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
                    pw.println(sb.toString());
                    pw.close();
                    //System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    Sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                    idCount++;
                }
                continue;
            }
            sb.append(line + "\r\n");
        }
```

But this only gives me the first 2 of the entries in separate parsed files. Leaving the 3rd one out for some reason.

The other way I was thinking about doing it was reading in all the lines using `.readAllLines()`, store the list as an array, loop through the lines to find "$#", get that line's index & then recursively write the lines starting at the index given.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this, or would be willing to explain to me why I'm only getting two of the three entries parsed?

Comment: You are getting only two of the sections because you write file for one section as soon as you find the next one. But after the thrid one, there is no next section, so it's not written.

Comment: Also, your snippet does not seem to be your actual code, please share your actual code. (the snippet does not create two files).

Comment: My apologies. @Eskapone was missing the sb.delete() line in the code that I uploaded. That’s essentially my code there.

Answer (score 2):

Short / quick fix is to write the contents of the StringBuilder once after your while loop like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int idCount = 1;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("<path to desired file>");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            //String line, date, user, userInfo, steamID;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //br.readLine();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.startsWith("$#")) {
                    if (sb.length() != 0) {
                        writeFile(sb.toString(), idCount);
                        System.out.println(sb);
                        sb.setLength(0);
                        idCount++;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                sb.append(line + "\r\n");
            }

            if (sb.length() != 0) {
                writeFile(sb.toString(), idCount);
                System.out.println(sb);
                idCount++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void writeFile(String content, int id) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("<path to desired dir>\\ID_" + id + ".txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
        pw.println(content);
        pw.close();
    }
```

I've changed two additional things:

the condition "line.substring(0,1).contains("$#")" did not work properly, the substring call only returns one character, but is compared to two characters -> never true. I changed that to use the 'startsWith' method.

After the content of the StringBuilder is written to file, you did not reset or empty it, resulting in the second and third file containing every previous blocks aswell (thrid file equals input then...). So thats done with "sb.setLength(0);".

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thank you so much, I didn’t even think about the fact that I wasn’t emptying the StringBuilder after. Thanks times a million! Been stuck on it for quite a while.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're interested in a 'better' or let's say another way of doing this let me know. But with output size that small using a StringBuilder is totally fine. Also, I'd appreciate an accepted answer ;)